# How to get a decimal number from root

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$^4\sqrt{250}$ = 3.98...

I get 3.98 from the calculation. 
Could you tell me how to get the decimal number from root number without the calculation?

Comment: Let $f(t)=t^{1/4}$. Then $f(x)\approx f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ (linear approximation). Take $a=256=4^4$ and $x=250$.

Comment: By "calculation", do you mean "calculator"?

Comment: What @AndréNicolas suggests is very well suited for *relative* errors: The relative error of $\sqrt[n] x$ is $\frac1n$ times the relative error for $x$ (assuming small errors, of course). As $250$ is $4^4$ minus 2%. Then $\sqrt[4]{250}$ is well approximated by $4$ minus $\tfrac 24$%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalized binomial theorem:

If $|a| < 1$ then
$(1+a)^d
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{d}{ n}a^n
$
where

$\binom{d}{ n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(d-k)}{n!}
$.

So the first few terms are
$(1+a)^d
\approx 1+da+\frac12 d(d-1)a^2+\frac16 d(d-1)(d-2)a^3
$.

In your case,

$\begin{array}\\
250^{1/4}
&=(256-6)^{1/4}\\
&=(2^8-6)^{1/4}\\
&=2^2(1-6/256)^{1/4}\\
&=4(1-3/128)^{1/4}\\
&\approx 4(1-(1/4)(3/128))
\qquad\text{(taking the first two terms)}\\
&\approx 4-3/128\\
&\approx 4-0.023\\
&= 3.977\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Use Newton's method.

We want to approximate $x=250^{1/4} \leftrightarrow x^4=250$, so have to find the roots of $f(x)=x^4-250$, which is done as follows:

Guess a value $x_0$ that you think is close to the answer. Let's say $6$.

The general algorithm is

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

which, in our case (with $f'(x)=4x^3$), becomes:

$$x_1=6-\frac{6^4-250}{4 \cdot 6^3} \approx 4.789...$$
and so on, getting a better and better approximation for each step.